# measurability w.r.t. Borel on extended real line

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Following Schilling I have shown for measurable functions $$u, v \in m \mathcal{A}/ \mathcal{\hat{B}}$$ that sums, differences, products and maxima/minima are again measurable whenever they are defined.
( here $\mathcal{\hat{B}}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on the extended real line )

There is a corollary that states without proof that the measurable functions $u$ and $v$ give $$\{u<v\} \in \mathcal{A}.$$ This is obvious if $u-v : (X,\mathcal{A}) \to (\mathbb{\hat{R}},\mathcal{\hat{B}} )$ is defined. However if there is some $x$ in the domain such that both functions take positive infinity (or negative infinity) there then we cannot argue via $\{u-v < 0\} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Since there is no reference in the corollary regarding the question whether $u - v$ is defined I must be missing something obvious ! Can somebody point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express $\{ u < v \}$ via the measurable functions $u 1_{\{ u \neq +\infty \}}$ and $v 1_{\{ v \neq - \infty \}}$.

Comment: Said more completely.  Prove measurability of all  sets $\{-\infty < u < v < +\infty\}$, $\{-\infty = u < v < +\infty\}$, $\{-\infty < u < v = +\infty\}$, $\{-\infty = u < v = +\infty\}$.